# Cannot delete data from datastore in aws-amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I am working with AWS amplify for the first time by following the docs. Everything is working except deletion of the data. Whenever I try to delete data from any of my table it gives the error

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'index' on 'IDBObjectStore': The specified index was not found.
> at Proxy. (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:34280:22)
> at IndexedDBAdapter. (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:25458:82)
> at step (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:23678:17)
> at Object.next (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:23609:14)
> at fulfilled (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:23563:24)

I have tried using all the ways mentioned in the amplify datastore docs, but I always get this error. Following is my graphql schema

```
type Profile @model @auth(rules: [{allow: groups, groups: ["SME"], operations: [read]}, {allow: owner}]) {
  email: String!
  name: String
  birthDate: String
  photo: String
  answers: [Answer!] @hasMany
}

type Questionnaire @model @auth(rules: [{allow: private, operations: [read]}, {allow: groups, groups: ["SME"], operations: [create, read, update, delete]}]) {
  detail: String!
  fields: [Field!] @hasMany
  next: Questionnaire @hasOne
  previous: Questionnaire @hasOne
}

type Field @model @auth(rules: [{allow: private, operations: [read]}, {allow: groups, groups: ["SME"], operations: [create, read, update]}]) {
  question: Questionnaire! @belongsTo
  label: String!
  options: [String!]!
  units: [Units]
  answers: [Answer!] @hasMany
}

type Answer @model @auth(rules: [{allow: groups, groups: ["SME"], operations: [read]}, {allow: owner, operations: [create, read, update]}]) {
  field: Field! @belongsTo
  answers: [String!]!
  unit: Units
}

enum Units {
  cm
  in
  ft
  kg
  lb
  sec
  min
  hrs
  days
  weeks
  months
}
```

I have set cognito userpool as default authorization type and conflict resolution to "merge".